# Checking if an object in a list exists and then removing it if it does not in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a script that creates a list of objects (data.frame). Then these objects are bound into a single .csv file. The issue is that every now and then, one of the scripts will come up empty due to blank elements. In turn, one of the objects will not exist.

I tried used

```
exist
```

but this has not worked well. I tried adding the following line but could not get it to work

```
object <- ifelse(exists(object)==True, object, c(NA,NA))
```

The endgoal of what I have is

```
dataset <- do.call("rbind", list(object, object2, object3, object4))
```

The issue is that this code does not work if one of those objects dont exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ls` and search for objects with a pattern. It will return only those objects which exist which we can `rbind`.

```
dataset <- do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = 'object')))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I should have specified that my objects are data.frames.

Comment: I don't think anything changes if the objects are dataframes. This should work for any object present in your global environment. Did you try the answer? Are you getting any error?

Comment: I got a null return from this. The scripts pull links from an RSS feed and return a data frame with 2 columns (one with links, one with RSS name). The end results is to create a single list. When there is a feed that didnt have news, though, then there is a non-defined objects. Then I cannot bind the dataframes together.

Comment: Ok..but this should work if your objects are created in global environment. Can you show the script that you are using (if that is not too long) ?