# Using R 'Exists' function when adding objects to a List

Tags: r, list, if-statement, automation, exists

Question from an R noob

I have some code I apply to a variable set of data, which may or may not contain data I am looking for. As such, my code generates an incomplete set of objects, which I then combine into an overall object.

```
obj1<-c(1,2,3)
obj2<-c(4,5,6)

MyList<-list(Obj1,Obj2,Obj3)
Error: object 'Obj3' not found
```

Because the data I am looking for is not always present, I sometimes generate null objects, which I have to manually remove from my list, when I try to combine all objects into a list:

```
MyList<-list(Obj1,Obj2)
```

How do I automate the check on objects, before adding them to the overall list to ensure only objects that actually exist are added to the List? I assume I need the 'if' and 'exists' function, but I cant quite work out how to combine them with the 'List' function

Comment: You can use the same approach as here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674085/checking-if-an-object-in-a-list-exists-and-then-removing-it-if-it-does-not-in-r

Comment: 1) R is case sensitive, the call to `list` would have given an error when parsing `Obj1`. 2) @RonakShah using your answer in your link, `mget(ls(pattern = '^obj'))` is the answer to this question. This should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Many thanks, RonakShah. Your comment answered my question :)